# Android Studio : How to keep variables from one java file to another

Tags: java, android, file, variables, export

I am developping an application which convert scanned data (barcode) to GoogleSheet data, and I am trying to transfer the barcode number (from Page2.java) into another java file (ListItem.java)

I saw that a usual way to do it is to create intents. So I did it.
But the toast I put in ListItem.java gives me "null" instead of the scanned number (for example 0123456789012)

Please, can you tell me where am I wrong ? Thank you so much !

1st Code (Page2.java , where I get "scanContent2", the variable I need) :

```
public class Page2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page2);
        scanBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_button2);

        scanBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public Button scanBtn2;
    public String scanContent2;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.scan_button2) {
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            scanContent2 = scanningResult.getContents();

            Intent intenta = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ListItem.class);
            intenta.putExtra("theScanContent2", scanContent2);
            startActivity(intenta);

        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

2nd code (ListItem.java, where I get "null" on the toast) :

```
public class ListItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

        String scanContent2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("theScanContent");

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "BarCode number: " + scanContent2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: One time you wrote "theScanContent2" and one time "theScanContent".

Comment: Thx I didn't saw it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **Listitem.java** in the following line,

```
String scanContent2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("theScanContent");
```

You are trying to get String with key **theScanContent**, while you are putting scanContent2 with key **theScanContent2** in Page2.java in line

```
intent.putExtra("theScanContent2", scanContent2);
```

Make sure the keys are **same** for the Intent while putting the data in intent and accessing the data from the intent to avoid getting null Results.